# Recharts - domains for two Y-axis

Tags: d3.js, recharts

I have a Recharts' ComposedChart (Area and Bar charts) but the domains for the data sets for each axis vary - one ranges from 0-100 and the other 0-2000. The dataset for the smaller range of data values becomes unusable.

Is it possible to have use different ranges for each axis?

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-composed-chart-forked-8degu?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add allowDataOverflow property to your Y-axis,here is an adaptatio of your code :

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-composed-chart-forked-mzv2z?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: sorry for that , here is the link : https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-composed-chart-forked-mzv2z?file=/src/App.tsx